# Is there a way to adjust existing coordinates graphically in MATLAB (e.g. click and drag)?

Tags: matlab, cursor, interactive

I have existing coordinates (e.g. from *ginput()*) that mark the vertices of a polygon around a region of interest (ROI) in an image.

I would like to display this polygon and be able to adjust the vertices (e.g. click and drag or click and click) to "fine tune" the ROI. For starters, I'd keep the number of vertices constant.

Is this possible in MATLAB?

I would like to implement this because I'm analysing hundreds of images that have similar (but not the same) ROIs - being able to adjust a few vertices over hundreds of images instead of drawing new ROIs for each image would save me a lot of time.

Thank you.

P.S. I am fairly new to MATLAB.

Comment: OK impoly() might be the answer...

Comment: Just found `roipoly()`.
Any additional suggestions/improvements still welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I saw your comment about `impoly()`, but if you're interested in a more "hands-on" approach using `ginput()`, here's some code that should do the trick! It assumes you have some initial vertices. You then click somewhere, and it finds the closest vertex and "moves" it to wherever you clicked.

```
function [] = test()

% Just setting some initial test vertices
v = [0,0; 0,1; 1,1; 1,0];

% Draw the inital polygon
ha = draw_edges(v,[]);

% Get the affected vertex and shift it
[x,y] = ginput(1);
distArr = sqrt((v(:,1)-x).^2+(v(:,2)-y).^2);
[~,idx] = min(distArr);
v(idx,:) = [x,y];

% Re-draw the polygon with the shifted vertex
draw_edges(v,ha);

end


function [ha] = draw_edges(v, ha)

if ~isempty(ha)
    delete(ha) 
end

if ~isempty(v)
    v(end+1,:) = v(1,:);
    ha = zeros(size(v,1)-1,1);
    for i = 1:size(v,1)-1
        v1 = v(i,:);
        v2 = v(i+1,:);
        ha(i) = line([v1(1) v2(1)], [v1(2) v2(2)]);
    end
end

end
```

Comment: p.s., you can stick the ginput section into a while loop and test for the "button" output while giving `ginput()` no arguments. Then the user can continuously modify the vertices until they press, for instance, enter.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your input. Yeah I was thinking along similar lines (i.e. updating nearest vertex) before I came across _impoly_. I'm glad you've put it into code form though (since I'm new to MATLAB, there is painful lag time between thinking of doing something and actually getting MATLAB to do it...), so I'll use it if I discover that I can't understand _impoly_. Since I'm still figuring that out, I won't close the question yet. Thanks again.